# sql connection from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Hi people may someone please assist here. Iam using vs2010 and I am trying to view my picture gallery website in the browser however I keep getting the following error

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]

   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5295887
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +242
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5307831
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +889
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions) +434
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +225
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +37
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +558
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +67
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32   waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions  userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1052
     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1    retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection,  TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory    connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +83
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32    maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +121
    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable,   IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +316
       System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +86
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1482
       System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback   callback) +21
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect() +101
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls() +55
       System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
        System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
       System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
       System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

Comment: check your connection string, try to open sql server and use same Server name

Answer (score 1):

The poor man's way to check your connection string (and any firewall issues) outside of code is this:

Go to Control Panel

Find ODBC

Go to System-DSN.

Create a new ODBC connection.

Create a Sql Server one.

Put in your credentials.

Test the Connection.

.........

If that works, then:

If you do this you're running under your own Identity.
Your website may be running under another Identity.
Keep that in mind.

But the ODBC is a quick way to check your credentials.

The error you are getting is basically "I can't connect to the Sql Server as you've defined in the connection string".

......

If you're confident that your credentials are correct, then here is the poor man's way to check for firewall issues.

Get this:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009

and "query" your sql server.  most likely, you'll ping on port 1433, but that could be different.

........

Firewall setup helpful url:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx

Comment: I keep getting this connection failed message how can I rectify that.I would like to connect automatically without credentials if possible

Comment: So it has nothing to do with "the code".  I made an edit.  Most likely you have a firewall issue IF you are very confident with the credentials you are sending.  You need to post your connection string (using substitute characters for any sensitive info like passwords)......there are multiple things that can go wrong with a connection string.  What kind of sql server are you trying to connect to?  Express, Local, MyServer\MyInstance?  Post some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection lost somehow, maybe because of network issue.

Comment: Also make sure that your connection string parameters are correct.